# C# List<object>

Tags: c#

There's a class:

```
public class SampleInformation
{
    public string Nutrient { get; set; }
    public decimal NutrientTotal { get; set; }
    public int NoSamples { get; set; }
    public decimal Average { get; set; }
    public decimal StandardDeviation { get; set; }
    public decimal CoVariance { get; set; }
    public decimal PSD { get; set; }
    public decimal NSD { get; set; }
}
```

and have created a list of the same.
Now while adding values, I would like to have 
PSD = Average + StandardDeviation and
NSD = Average - StandardDeviation

My code goes as:

```
sampleInfoList.Add(new SampleInformation
            {
                Nutrient = "Dry Matter",
                NoSamples = CalculateSampleCount(dryMatter),
                Average = CalculateAverage(dryMatter),
                StandardDeviation = CalculateStandardDeviation(dryMatter),
                CoVariance = CalculateCoVariance(dryMatter),
                NSD = 0,
                PSD = 0,
                NutrientTotal = 0
            });
```

How can I have something like

```
 sampleInfoList.Add(new SampleInformation
            {
                Nutrient = "Dry Matter",
                NoSamples = CalculateSampleCount(dryMatter),
                Average = CalculateAverage(dryMatter),
                StandardDeviation = CalculateStandardDeviation(dryMatter),
                CoVariance = CalculateCoVariance(dryMatter),
                NSD = Average - StandardDeviation,
                PSD = Average + StandardDeviation,
                NutrientTotal = 0
            });
```

I do not want to create another method and pass the list to calculate NSD and PSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create NSD and PSD as properties:

```
public class SampleInformation
{
    public string Nutrient { get; set; }
    public decimal NutrientTotal { get; set; }
    public int NoSamples { get; set; }
    public decimal Average { get; set; }
    public decimal StandardDeviation { get; set; }
    public decimal CoVariance { get; set; }
    public decimal PSD { get { return Average + StandardDeviation } }
    public decimal NSD { get { return Average - StandardDeviation } }
}
```

then it will be calculated for you and you can just add new instance like that:

```
sampleInfoList.Add(new SampleInformation
    {
        Nutrient = "Dry Matter",
        NoSamples = CalculateSampleCount(dryMatter),
        Average = CalculateAverage(dryMatter),
        StandardDeviation = CalculateStandardDeviation(dryMatter),
        CoVariance = CalculateCoVariance(dryMatter),
        NutrientTotal = 0
    });
```

Comment: I have further extended the question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771936/c-sharp-listobject

Answer (score 1):

you may try ;

```
public class SampleInformation
{
    public string Nutrient { get; set; }
    public decimal NutrientTotal { get; set; }
    public int NoSamples { get; set; }
    public decimal Average { get; set; }
    public decimal StandardDeviation { get; set; }
    public decimal CoVariance { get; set; }
    public decimal PSD { get { return Average + StandardDeviation; } private set { } }
    public decimal NSD { get{ return Average-StandardDeviation;} private set{} }
}
```