# C# List<object> and List

Tags: c#

Further extending the question:

[C# List<object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771936/c-sharp-listobject)

```
public class SampleInformation
{
    public string Nutrient { get; set; }
    public decimal NutrientTotal { get; set; }
    public int NoSamples { get; set; }
    public decimal Average { get; set; }
    public decimal StandardDeviation { get; set; }
    public decimal CoVariance { get; set; }
    public decimal PSD { get { return Average + StandardDeviation } }
    public decimal NSD { get { return Average - StandardDeviation } }
}
```

The above class calculates average, SD, CoVar, etc.
The above class gaves me output as:

```
Nutrient | Average | # Samples | SD | CoVar
```

I would like to extend the above to and bind it to a list

```
Nutrient | Average | # Samples | SD | CoVar | Item1 | Item2 | ...
XXX | Average | # Samples | SD | CoVar | Value for XXX for item 1 | Value for XXX for item 2 | ...
yyy | Average | # Samples | SD | CoVar | Value for YYY for item 1 | Value for YYY for item 2 | ...
```

Any quick help ?

Comment: It is not clear as to what, exactly, you are trying to do.  Can you elaborate a bit.  It sounds like you are just asking how to create a list of the above object.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of SampleInformation objects by:

```
List<SampleInformation> sampleList = new List<SampleInformation>(); //Creates the list
SampleInformation sample = new SampleInformation(); //Your object
sampleList.Add(sample); //Add your object to the list
```

Is this what you are looking for?